# Explain syntax of delegate invocation c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, delegates

In the code from this link: http://c-sharp-programming.blogspot.com/2008/07/cross-thread-operation-not-valid.html, a delegate is used to update a text box's value from a worker thread.

I can basically see what's happening, but the syntax of this line specifically:

```
label1.Invoke(del, new object[] { newText });
```

is confusing to me.  Can someone explain it please? Why do we use a new object array syntax for the delegate when there's only one parameter?

**Full code:**

```
delegate void updateLabelTextDelegate(string newText);
private void updateLabelText(string newText)
{
 if (label1.InvokeRequired)
 {
     // this is worker thread
     updateLabelTextDelegate del = new updateLabelTextDelegate(updateLabelText);
     label1.Invoke(del, new object[] { newText });
 }
 else
 {
     // this is UI thread
     label1.Text = newText;
 }
}
```

Comment: It is a mistake, label1.Invoke() isn't a delegate.  Just write `label1.Invoke(del, newText);`

Comment: Was he saying label1.Invoke() is a delegate? I didn't read that. Also, good pointing out you can use a single param without the explicit object[] thanks to params.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TL;DR:

`Control.Invoke` is calling [DynamicInvoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.delegate.dynamicinvoke%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) on your delegate which takes an object array of parameters to work with any delegate type.

//

The keyword [delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/900fyy8e%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) in C# in analagous to specifying a type of function pointer. You can use that *type* to pass methods of a specific signature. In your example, the signature is for a method that takes 1 arg (a string) and returns nothing (void). The method `updateLabelText` matches that sig. The line:

```
updateLabelTextDelegate del = new updateLabelTextDelegate(updateLabelText);
```

Is just a full-text way of saying:

```
updateLabelTextDelegate del = updateLabelText;
```

Then, you can pass your variable `del`, which is now a pointer to the method `updateLabelText` to the `Control.Invoke` method.

```
label1.Invoke(del, new object[] { newText });
```

Which thanks to `params` being using in the `Control.Invoke` signature, you don't even have to explicitly say it's an `object[]`

```
label1.Invoke(del, newText);
```

The `Invoke` takes an array of objects, which it'll use as the args to the delegate given. (Yes your update method takes one string arg, keep reading) With your variable `del`, you *could* call `updateLabelText` yourself:

```
del(newText);
```

Which would essentially be the same as:

```
updateLabelText(newText);
```

Inside `Control.Invoke`, they are calling your `del` method, but it doesn't **have** to know how many args it takes thanks to some helper methods on delegates. You would find something like this:

**EDIT** I did some deep digging for science, the [invocation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.delegate.dynamicinvoke%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) internally is more like:

```
del.DynamicInvoke(args);
```

Where `args` is an `object[]`. For more info on things you can do with your delegate variable (which is of type Delegate), read more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the method signature of [Control.Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1hetckb.aspx), you'll see it takes `params Object[] args`.  You can either pass `object[] args` or a single argument.

Answer (score 2):

The object array is passed to the delegate's `Invoke` method. In this case `updateLabelTextDelegate` takes a single `string` parameter, hence the single element in the array.

In fact the array does not need to be explicitly created, and

```
label1.Invoke(del, newText)
```

is also valid.

Comment: +1 for not having use `new object[]`, but I would point out that is only an option thanks to `params`

Answer (score 1):

First, it's worth noting that this isn't calling `Invoke` on the delegate - it's calling `Invoke` on the *control*. Now if you look at the signature of [`Control.Invoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1hetckb.aspx) being used here, it's this:

```
public Object Invoke(
    Delegate method,
    params Object[] args
)
```

If the method took *one specific* delegate type, it could take the appropriate parameter types for that delegate. In *your* case your delegate only takes one parameter, but suppose we wanted to pass in an `Action<string, string, int>` - using the very general approach above, we can do that with:

```
control.Invoke(someDelegate, new object[] { "foo", "bar", 10 });
```

So the answer is that the `object[]` is there to provide generality, because the delegate type is left general too. It's a bit like `MethodInfo.Invoke` - without knowing at compile-time how many parameters there are, a value of type `object[]` is the best way of allowing various situations.